# Screen problem in Motorola moto g 2ng gen

Tags: motorola-moto-g

There are black dotted lines over all on the screen. The touch works fine but black dotted lines randomly appear all over the screen.

[image]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

Here is the screenshot. They appeared a day after I bought the phone

Comment: Are you standing next to a dirty sprinkler maybe? Sorry for the bad joke, but we need much more details here – e.g. when did that start, did you change anything shortly before it (i.e. what might have led to the issue), etc. A photo might prove helpful as well as a screenshot, best both (to see whether it's a hardware or software issue).

Comment: This is most likely either a hardware issue or a software issue at the OS level. I had a device that I was using CM on that would do something similar whenever I rotated the screen. Did you buy it from a store or 3rd party? Have you loaded custom software?